# Guix Error when trying to make sphinx documentation

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, guix

Good afternoon. The OS used is Guix

```
guix --version
(GNU Guix) 938a47c86d7bea785f33f42834c5c1f3dfa594b0

guix package --list-installed
make                    4.3                 out /gnu/store/c5kpgdinijrqwkx63q4zyqcwclkn5b2s-make-4.3
git                     2.41.0              out /gnu/store/57bpibp6jay9q11xhasw75cclkyq9d6h-git-2.41.0
texinfo                 7.0.3               out /gnu/store/ri8lw41rpi24av3gy2b779iw790a9nln-texinfo-7.0.3
translate-shell         0.9.7.1             out /gnu/store/g5ki8alshcbv8nxd912vch1n089hwh36-translate-shell-0.9.7.1
groff                   1.22.4              out /gnu/store/4swp36jfinc60sfhm1q3mxj2h2mpnc8z-groff-1.22.4
roffit                  0.12-1.b59e6c855    out /gnu/store/m5hxiswy6sl819va2axjwivgyapjfpyc-roffit-0.12-1.b59e6c855
firefox                 119.0               out /gnu/store/phagnzcwb9nxfqbmm65284jrvhlf73s4-firefox-119.0
gnome-shell-extensions  42.3                out /gnu/store/4f2qcnhmb9g3l2500m28vnblnfw9mg03-gnome-shell-extensions-42.3
python                  3.10.7              out /gnu/store/i2gnz4m9rpixbqrmd4x46r1xnh9adbaa-python-3.10.7
python-sphinx           5.1.1               out /gnu/store/560q0k85lg9kfvpspc2fmmf9ng7ki6dd-python-sphinx-5.1.1
gcc-toolchain           13.2.0              out /gnu/store/m9lkrb2y14jwgx56vdhy9cs6yngm8wjc-gcc-toolchain-13.2.0
python-pip              23.1                out /gnu/store/724pw1f9m1k5fsxhzfmsfjvc5ivkhm4p-python-pip-23.1
python-sphinx-alabaster-theme   0.7.12              out /gnu/store/cjd7nq31lvlpyjmz2z61l41ga2dhigg5-python-sphinx-alabaster-theme-0.7.12
python-nbsphinx         0.8.8               out /gnu/store/brgppd3ssnc45swk3p6k6f8wgll6ryd5-python-nbsphinx-0.8.8
perl                    5.36.0              out /gnu/store/h0hsl8ncw6d6p6274q5xzh67g2biaia9-perl-5.36.0
```

There was a difficulty in assembling the Linux kernel documentation. Repository cloned **https://github.com/linux-kernel-labs/linux.git** and **https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git**.

Build according to the attached manuals in the repositories was not successful. Created an environment on Ubuntu
python and compiled a guide to python and sphinx

```
make VENVDIR=.../python/env/ venv
source .../python/env/bin/activate
(env) $ python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
# Сборка документации
(env) $ sphinx-build -bhtml .../dirRstFls .../dirOutDocHtml
```

I'm interested in the possibility of assembling documentation for the apache and git web server in Guix; a script was used in ubuntu
with java build.sh to build apache documentation, to build git manual - asciidoc. I saw the httpd package
in guix. Translated Guix documentation into my language (Russian) (part of the translation already existed), without documentation
As for the Linux kernel, my learning to program has reached a dead end. Translated documentation for python3.12 and
sphinx. From what I learned from a quick read of the translated manuals, I was able to collect documentation on Ubuntu
for the Linux kernel from the repository **https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git**.  From the repository **https://github.com/linux-kernel-labs/linux.git**
It didn't work out that way. It turns out that in order to collect documentation on the Linux kernel on Ubuntu, you will need to study how it works
miracle store snap packages Ubuntu, python, sphinx, Perl and so on. Maybe there are development guides in GNU?
Linux kernels in Texinfo format?
Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the Guix error? What do you mean by "There was a difficulty..." and "...was not successful"?

Comment: Hello. Added output when trying to build.

Comment: It is still  unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Hello mzjn. In the GUIX environment, I can't collect documentation for the Linux kernel, on Ubuntu I had the same problem. Fails to use the Python and Sphinx bundle correctly in Guix